# How do I skip special buffers when killing the current buffer?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I have some code in my `.emacs` that prevents it from showing some pre-defined special buffers when I'm using `previous-buffer` and `next-buffer`:

```
(defadvice next-buffer (after avoid-messages-buffer-in-next-buffer)
  (when (string= "*Messages*" (buffer-name)) (next-buffer))
  (when (string= "*Completions*" (buffer-name)) (next-buffer))
  (when (string-match "\*tramp.*\*" (buffer-name)) (previous-buffer))
   ... and so on)
```

This works great, but I'd like to have the same functionality for <kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>k</kbd>. So far, I've tried writing the same kind of function `(defadvice (after kill-buffer) ...)`, but that doesn't seem to work.

How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
(defvar no-kill-buffers
  '("*Messages*"
    ;; ...
    ))

(defadvice kill-buffer (around no-kill-some-buffers activate)
  (unless (member (buffer-name) no-kill-buffers)
    ad-do-it))
```

The reason your advice didn't work is that it was "after" advice, meaning it didn't run until after the normal `kill-buffer` logic had completed. (That's the `after` in `(after avoid-message-buffer-in-next-buffer)`.

`around` advice let's you put custom logic either before or after the advised command and even control whether it runs at all. The `ad-do-it` symbol is what tells it if and when to run the normal `kill-buffer` routine.

**Edit:**

Having re-read your question I think I may have misunderstood it. If you're looking to skip a special buffer that would have been displayed after killing a buffer then your approach is basically correct. Have you [activated the advice](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Activation-of-Advice.html)?

You can either evaluate `(ad-activate 'avoid-messages-buffer-in-next-buffer)` or include `activate` at the end of the argument list to `defadvice` as I did in my example.